# How to detect if redirect was invoked

Tags: go

I have the following code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func fooHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Here an if condition, if should redirect or not
    http.Redirect(w, r, "http://www.google.com", 301)
    // Do something....
    // Call function if redirect was invoked

}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", fooHandler)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

How can I detect, if redirect was written in the response object?

Comment: Typically if you use http.Redirect, you would want to return immediately so the browser can follow the redirect. May I ask what code would come after the redirect? Also, unless you're using some framework where you have access to the underlying instance of whatever is implementing http.ResponseWriter, you won't be able to know what its state is.

Comment: Because I have a wrapper struct, that is going to render html file or not, if the redirect was set, then is should not going to render html file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want something more along these lines:

```
func fooHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Here an if condition, if should redirect or not
    if needToRedirect {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "http://www.google.com", 301)
        return
    }
    // Do something....
    // Call function if redirect was invoked
    // render template
}
```

Normally in go we follow the *exit* *early* mantra. In your example, once you've identified that the user needs to be redirected (ignoring any other logging you may want to do) it would be best to return immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the status of the response (for [3xx redirection status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection)), as in this [http REST driver](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/packer-azure/blob/35def56ff079cb3d46d0fc66017ad0de64b57973/packer/builder/azure/driver_restapi/driver/DriverREST_tls.go#L124-L133):

```
    req, err = http.NewRequest(verb, url, body)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for k, v := range headers {
        req.Header.Add(k, v)
    }

    resp, err = d.httpClient.Do(req)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    log.Printf("Exec responce: %v\n", resp)

    statusCode := resp.StatusCode


    if statusCode == 307 { // Temporary Redirect

        // For instance (put your own code here)

        redirectUrl, ok := resp.Header["Location"]
        if !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("%s %s", "Failed to redirect:", "header key 'Location' wasn't found")
        }
        log.Printf("Redirecting: '%s' --> '%s'", url, redirectUrl[0])
        url = redirectUrl[0]
        continue

    }
```

Comment: Actually he can't do this - in this example `resp` is an `*http.Response`, which you can access fields in. In the OPs example, his response is an `http.ResponseWriter` (an interface) which he can't access fields in (unless he knows the underlying implementation).

Comment: @user114241 agreed. Maybe a type assertion might work (if the OP knows about the underlying type). Let's wait for the OP's feedback.

Comment: Totally, I'm more suspecting the OP might be using/writing a framework that renders a template tied to the method receiver/method when the method finishes execution. In such a case, the framework would mostly likely have a bool field (or something similar) that is set as soon as any call to `Write()` is made (to signify if there was stuff written, in turn it should check the status code before it renders the template).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I must agree with responses here that say it's probably best to return immediately after redirecting.  If, however, you are determined to do some other stuff afterward (whether or not you redirected), followed by a function that is called only if the redirect was used, then you could do something along the lines of this:

```
func fooHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if needToRedirect {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "http://www.google.com", 301)
        defer func() {
            // stuff that only happens if redirected, but happens last
        }()
    }
    // stuff that happens whether redirected or not
    // note that this will happen before the deferred func is called
}
```

Here's the documentation for defer: http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover

It's pretty simple.  The deferred call will execute after the surrounding function (fooHandler) returns, but it will still have access to anything in fooHandler's scope, including named return values.  It's also important to note that the deferred function will be called even during a panic, although nothing will happen unless it calls `recover()`.

EDIT: Here's a silly example of how it works: http://play.golang.org/p/5TgCv4O_rA

Comment: Please try to avoid something like this though, `defers` are still relatively [slow in Go](http://fr.slideshare.net/derekcollison/gophercon-2014) and webservers should be as fast as possible. This also makes the code much less intuitive to read. This would also be more functional if the defer was the first thing in this function, and referenced a variable that could be set as a flag inside the `if needToRedirect { ... }`.

Comment: I didn't know defers were slow.  TIL, thanks for the lesson.  Also, if one were to use them, I do agree with your readability recommendation.